# Django translation and py2exe

Tags: python, django, translation, py2exe

I have just compiled my django application to an exe using **py2exe**. But I don't have any idea how to make **django translation** work (I mean built in translation, not my own translation files).
There is LANGUAGE_CODE set in my settings file, I also tried importing django.utils.translation and django.conf.locale.pl in py2exe options includes. I also tried but I didn't manage to import LC_MESSAGE files from django/conf/locale/pl using data_files in py2exe setup. I think LC_MESSAGE files are the main problem but I don't know how to put them into my compilation. Is it possible to change py2exe compiled project language? How and how import language files? My py2exe setup files are similar to http://misunderstandings.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/django-desktop-app/ .

**Edit:** I post here code lines, where I'm trying import translation util:

```
'django.utils.translation.*',
'django.conf.locale.pl.*',
```

I have also tried:

```
'django.utils.translation.trans_null',
'django.utils.translation.trans_real',
'django.utils.translation.__init__',
'django.conf.locale.pl.__init__',
'django.conf.locale.pl.formats',
```

But as I had though it doesn't matter. In build\bdist.win-amd64\winexe\collect-2.7\django there are both folders conf/locale and utils/translation with proper files. But of course not LC_MESSAGE folder. I try to import it using:

```
py2exe_data_files += add_path_tree( python_path, 'lib\site-packages\django\conf\locale\pl' )
```

As I checked it finds files in this folder but do nothing with them.

My setup file (it's long so I put it on the sourcepod): http://www.sourcepod.com/fcmpkn17-5519

Maybe I forgot to include something but I don't have any idea what could it be..

Comment: Do you get errors? What goes wrong when you try? If you got errors post the entire error here.

Comment: No errors. Just english language in form validation errors and in admin.

Comment: I have just realized that when I copy locale directory from django/conf to my app, django uses it. But I still cant't put it into py2exe compilation, even if all translation files are located in my app directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved! And in so easy way..

As https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/ says we can put locale files into different localizations. So I copy all locale files from django/conf to my template folder.

This line of my py2exe setup.py copy it to my compilation with templates:

```
py2exe_data_files += add_path_tree( '', 'templates' )
```

The last thing to do is to set locale path in settings file:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
'templates/locale',
)
```